# How can I take my output (IDs) and use it to Get more informaiton

Tags: c#

My first question got -4 votes rightfully. Hopefully I net positive with a better question.

Using C#, I called hackernews API to Get the IDs of the top 500 stories.I receied the 500 ids (comma separated). 
- I want to learn how to use the IDs to call another API in order to retrieve the title and URL for each ID and store the output in a text file. 
The next steps I would logically take are to
- Store ID output in variable. (I believe its in the 'reader' variable in the code) 
- Use the stored values to somehow call the next API (I can insert each ID into the URL to get individual info but is there a Method i can use to indicate the code to get information from one id then move to the next if that makes sense?) 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/.json?print=pretty'.

I think I have to parse the data so I'm looking into that but any guidance or pointing I a direction is helpful. Thanks!

This is the code I used to get the data.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Request_API_Using_WebRequest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            WebRequest.Create("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");


            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            }
            //close the response.... does this close the prompt?
            response.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if i understood your question but, i would extract the id's to a list   List<string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(responseFromServer); And after that save them in a BD, InMemory, etc. Then you have the list of ID's and you can call the api

Comment: Hi I appreciate the response I will try this.